# Awk tab-delimited columns with comma-delimited values, split them up

Tags: regex, awk

I have a file with columns like this:

```
TNFRSF14 chr1 2487803,2489164,2489781,2491261,2492062,2493111,2494303,2494586, 2488172,2489273,2489907,2491417,2492153,2493254,2494335,2497061,
ID3 chr1 23884420,23885425,23885617, 23884906,23885510,23886285,
```

In case the tabs cannot be seen on your browser:

```
TNFRSF14"\t"chr1"\t"2487803,2489164,2489781,2491261,2492062,2493111,2494303,2494586,"\t"2488172,2489273,2489907,2491417,2492153,2493254,2494335,2497061,
ID3"\t"chr1"\t"23884420,23885425,23885617,"\t"23884906,23885510,23886285,
```

I would like to have the output say:

```
TNFRSF14 chr1 2487803 2488172
TNFRSF14 chr1 2489164 2489273
...
ID3 chr1 23885425 23885510
ID3 chr1 23885617 23886285
```

As you can see, my original input is of varying lengths in columns 3 and 4, but the length of column 3 will always equal column 4. So far I have been able to split the files into varying column lengths, and have a python script that can place them. I was hoping there was a way for awk to do this though!

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You want to split the third tab-delimited field on commas and then prefix the first two fields on a line for each comma-delimited field?

Comment: What should be the output if there are more fields in column 3 than in column 4, or vice versa? What to do if there are more or less than 4 columns, or can we assume that the layout is clean and the number of fields is always the same in columns 3 and 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try to use [split function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

```
gawk '{
  split($3,a,","); 
  split($4,b,","); 
  for(i=1; i<length(a); i++){ 
    print $1, $2, a[i], b[i];
  }
}' input
```

**Note**: length(array) is gnu-awk specific

you get:

```
TNFRSF14 chr1 2487803 2488172
TNFRSF14 chr1 2489164 2489273
TNFRSF14 chr1 2489781 2489907
TNFRSF14 chr1 2491261 2491417
TNFRSF14 chr1 2492062 2492153
TNFRSF14 chr1 2493111 2493254
TNFRSF14 chr1 2494303 2494335
TNFRSF14 chr1 2494586 2497061
ID3 chr1 23884420 23884906
ID3 chr1 23885425 23885510
ID3 chr1 23885617 23886285
```

Comment: or `substr` after using `index` to find the position of the first comma

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    n = split($3,a,/,/)
    split($4,b,/,/)
    for (i=1;i<n;i++) {
        print $1, $2, a[i], b[i]
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
TNFRSF14        chr1    2487803 2488172
TNFRSF14        chr1    2489164 2489273
TNFRSF14        chr1    2489781 2489907
TNFRSF14        chr1    2491261 2491417
TNFRSF14        chr1    2492062 2492153
TNFRSF14        chr1    2493111 2493254
TNFRSF14        chr1    2494303 2494335
TNFRSF14        chr1    2494586 2497061
ID3     chr1    23884420        23884906
ID3     chr1    23885425        23885510
ID3     chr1    23885617        23886285
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F',? ' '
{
    split($3, a, /,/)
    split($4, b, /,/)
    for (i in a) print $1, $2, a[i], b[i]
}' file
```

Comment: That will scramble the order of the subfields in $3 and $4 and print a row with only $1 and $2 populated somewhere. Try it.

Comment: @EdMorton: But that would make the three answers ...the same... :)

Comment: You could use `for (i=1;i in a;i++)` - it'd still give you a final row with just $1 and $2 and nothing else unless you added an extra check but at least then the contents of a and b would be output in the original order. FWIW although the 3 answers look the same, of the 2 that would produce the correct output, mine would be the most efficient and not be gawk-specific :-).